# File explorer to display INTERNAL STORAGE images

Tags: android, file, storage, explorer

I believe that this question is an easy one for yours, but a very difficult one for me.

I'm developing an Android application that, among other functionalities, should provide users a way to select multiple pre-defined images. Since those images will be private and they will not be downloaded from any site, I thought to include them in the `INTERNAL STORAGE` of the application. Then, I just created a `raw` folder in the resource tree of the Android Studio project, and I placed several images there. My intention is to create a File Explorer dialog that displays those images, in order to allow users to select several ones. I tried to implement the native Android File Explorer, but it doesn't seem to have access to the `INTERNAL STORAGE`.

What is the most optimal way to develop this? Is there any file dialog class to help me doing so? Would it be better to place the images on the `EXTERNAL STORAGE`? How could I do it?

I don't want any code to help me with this, just a few guidelines! :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use assets?
Look example [code](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/)

// load image

```
try 
{   
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("avatar.jpg");
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);  
    mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
    ims .close();
}
catch(IOException ex) 
{
    return;
}
```